# Inspect Subdirectories of an Excluded Folder with PHP CodeSniffer

Tags: phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I am attempting to configure my `phpcs.xml` (PHP CodeSniffer configuration file) so that I can exclude all directories from inspection within a folder **except for those that I specify.**

For those familiar with `.gitignore`, an equivalent would be something like this so that "ButIncludeThisOne" is included in version control.

```
/ignoreContentsWithin/*
!/ignoreContentsWithin/ButIncludeThisOne
```

#### What I have tried

Here is my `phpcs.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyRuleset">
    ...
    <!-- Exclude Plugin Folders. -->
    <exclude-pattern>/cms/wp-content/plugins/*</exclude-pattern>
    <!-- But Inspect My Plugin Folder. -->
    <include-pattern>/cms/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/*</include-pattern>
</ruleset>
```

Using the example above, I *can* specify every single folder within the plugins folder *except* for `myplugin` and this works, but it is not ideal. (I would have to remember to exclude any new plugin from inspection)

If I remove the `exclude-pattern` directive, files within the `myplugin` folder are sniffed, so I know that it is working otherwise.

Comment: This issue can be helpful --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/70289238/5882271

Answer (score 3):

TLTR; for your specific example:

```xml
<exclude-pattern type="relative">^(?!cms/wp-content/plugins/myplugin).+</exclude-pattern>
```

You can use regex in there but `*` will be used as `.*`

Check out [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/cCiXqA/1/) with negative lookahead. The `type="relative"` is important here.

```xml
<exclude-pattern type="relative">^(?!plugins/(arve-|advanced-re|edd-)).+</exclude-pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - gave it a test and still can't verify that this works. Maybe I'm having trouble understanding the type="relative" attribute/can't find anything useful in the documentation. Is this relative to the configuration file?

Comment: Yes its relative to the config file, and it works without slash prefix.