# How to exclude everything except some directories from PHP Code Sniffer inspections in .phpcs.xml?

Tags: php, regex, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I would like to exclude **everything except some directories** from `PHP Code Sniffer` inspection in my project. Something similar like git repo exclusions with .gitignore

I had the idea that `regex` with negative lookahead could be used with `<exclude-pattern`>. I tried:

```
<exclude-pattern>^(?!wp-content\/plugins\/customplugin\/*$|wp-content\/themes\/customtheme\/*$).+</exclude-pattern>
```

Consequently, I expected PHPCS to only scan the `wp-content/plugins/customplugin/` and `wp-content/themes/customtheme/`. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
Registering sniffs in the Project standard... DONE (138 sniffs registered)
Creating file list... DONE (0 files in queue)
```

How to achieve this in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the intended goal, we must modify the regular expression:

```
<exclude-pattern>^(?!.*\/wp-content\/plugins\/customplugin|.*\/wp-content\/themes\/customtheme).*</exclude-pattern>
```

Note that it may be possible to resolve this issue in a different way in the future thanks to [this](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/1884) ticket in the CodeSniffer repository